# How to set max-height with calc from angular component?

Tags: css, angular

My solution:

```
<div
 [style.max-height]="'calc(100% -' + (actualTaskListHeight+90) + 'px)'"> 
</div>
```

Its didn't work. Why?
My purpose is calculating height depends on other div. Here I use const actualTaskListHeight